# Can't see Webserver from LAN - NAT Issue?

Tags: firewall, nat, zyxel

I just got a ZyXEL USG50 and it's more complex than I'm used to.

Traffic from WAN is going to my websever as desired thanks to a firewall and NAT rule.

The problem is, when trying to request a domain from inside the LAN, the browser times out and doesn't resolve the site address.

Obviously this is a NAT problem, but I can't figure out how to set it properly.

The weird thing is, when using puTTY to SSH to the server using the domain name, it works just fine. Obviously, SFTP works fine as well from the LAN.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You say "when trying to request a domain from inside the LAN, the browser times out and doesn't resolve the site address.".
If this is a resolution problem then it's DNS who is involved. But how do you know the resolution doesn't work?
What does your dns replies when querying for the domain internally from LAN and externally from WAN?
As a first step, check that to make sure that this is indeed a pb with resoution.
I suspect you might resolve to 2 different addresses depending on wether you're trying to resolve on a public dns or on your local dns server. Then you migth have to tweak iptable or daemon binding (more likely to be iptables if the browser times really out).